# How to Create a Custom ID in Access 2010

Tags: ms-access, macros, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2010

The title of this Question may not be accurate because I wasn't sure how to ask the question.

Is there A way to have an ID field in AC 2010 the has a constant part and then a part of the ID that the user will enter in?

EXAMPLE: "EMP9066"

-I would like the "EMP" part of the ID to be constant at all times and the user should not be able to change it and the "9066" is a four digit that the user will be asked to type in.

Please Help.

_ Remember this is not SQL just basic access with some macros.

Thanks

Comment: Do not forget that this may lead to confusion when working with either DAO or ADO recordsets, because they will not see the format.

Comment: Is this ID field a Primary Key?  If so then user's shouldn't really be able to see Primary Key's and certainly not be responsible for entering them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access has a data type called autonumber which will generate a unique number for each record automatically but it does not allow for the alpha prefix.

if it is indeed constant then the simplest approach is to prefix with it for display, ie in the table the field would be called recId (for example) and you would view the rows via a query with a calculated column

EmpId: "EMP" & format$(RecId,"0000")

Comment: Thanks for your input but i played around with it and found it! :) Thanks Though. I just used "EMP"0000 in the input mask.